# how to debug a release

Tags: c++, visual-studio-debugging

I have a debug .dll build that uses libcurl to send HTTP requests, all working fine.

With the release, the program that uses my .dll doesn't like it, the program maker recommended
make the libcurl.dll as delay-loaded, and calling LoadLibrary

so I did this
`LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\VirtualDJ\\Plugins64\\SoundEffect\\libcurl.dll"));`
and pointed Linker>input>delay loaded dlls to libcurl.dll [literally that]

It makes the plugin compatible again but I'm no longer getting communication.
I'm not sure how to proceed.

Is my LoadLibrary syntax correct?
I've been told debug the release, and I followed all these properties changes
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-debug-a-release-build?view=msvc-160
but I don't understand how you would run the release.

I'm pretty new at this so the simpler it is explained the better.
C++ Visual Studio 19

Comment: Make sure all compiled dll are compiled with abi compatible options (like debug iterators)

Answer (score -1):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=msvc-160 the delay loaded dlls has nuances which you should consider. I didn't use this, but I use `LoadLibrary/GetProcAdress/FreeLibrary` always without any problems so I suggest you to try this way.
You can try to debug a release in the WinDbg. Just need to set paths to source code and PDB files. Sometimes WinDbg can be more useful than Visual Studio. More details about WinDbg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools